# How to change background color of selected item in a listview on xamarin form?

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, background-color, selecteditem

I have ListView like this

> ```
>      <StackLayout Spacing="0">
>         <ListView x:Name="lvMenu" SeparatorColor="Green">
>           <ListView.ItemTemplate>
>             <DataTemplate>
>               <ViewCell>
>                 <StackLayout Padding="10">
>                   <Label HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="#03a9f4" />
>                 </StackLayout>
>               </ViewCell>
>             </DataTemplate>
>           </ListView.ItemTemplate>
>         </ListView>
>       </StackLayout>
> ```

Also have ItemSelected event handler like this

> ```
>     lvMenu.ItemSelected += GotoPage;
>     private void GotoPage(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
>     {
>         var item = e.SelectedItem as MasterPageItem;
>         if (item != null)
>         {
>             //Change bg
>             if (item.Title == "Logout")
>             {
>                 LogoutUser();
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 NavigationPage nPage = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType)) {
>                     Title = item.Title
>                 };
>                 this.Detail = nPage;
>                 this.IsPresented = false;
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     public class MasterPageItem
>     {
>         public string Title { get; set; }
>         public Type TargetType { get; set; }
>     }
> ```

I have tried default listview template, but no luck.
Can anyone suggest how to change the selected item's default background color?

Answer (score 4):

Use this code

```
List.ItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (List.SelectedItem != null || e.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
    }
};
```